# not able to make SCE script working

Tags: openscap

I'm trying to use SCE script in openscap ds file and all I get is "notchecked" status

here is my ds file:

```
<ns0:data-stream-collection xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                                                    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                                                    xmlns:ns0="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap/source/1.2"
                                                    xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                                    xmlns:ns10="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2"
                                                    xmlns:ns12="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                                    xmlns:ns14="http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0"
                                                    xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"
                                                    xmlns:oval-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5"
                                                    xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5"
                                                    xmlns:ind-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#independent"
                                                    xmlns:unix-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#unix"
                                                    xmlns:red-def="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5#linux"
                                                    xmlns:ns9="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/ocil/2.0"
                                                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                                    id="scap_1_collection_1"
                                                    schematron-version="1.2">

    <ns0:data-stream id="scap_1_datastream_1" scap-version="1.2" timestamp="2018-12-13T04:28:31" use-case="OTHER">

            <ns0:checklists>
                    <ns0:component-ref id="scap_1_cref_1" ns1:href="#scap_1_comp_1">
                            <ns2:catalog>
                                    <ns2:uri name="scap_1_catalog_1" uri="#scap_1_cref_3"/>
                            </ns2:catalog>
                    </ns0:component-ref>
            </ns0:checklists>

            <ns0:checks>
                    <ns0:component-ref id="scap_1_cref_3" ns1:href="#scap_1_comp_2"/>
            </ns0:checks>

    </ns0:data-stream>

    <ns0:component id="scap_1_comp_1" timestamp="2017-10-19T23:40:42">

            <ns10:Benchmark id="xccdf_1_benchmark_1" resolved="1" style="SCAP_1.2">

                    <ns10:status date="2018-04-10">draft</ns10:status>
                    <ns10:title>Guide to the Secure ACME</ns10:title>
                    <ns10:description>This guide presents a catalog of security rules</ns10:description>
                    <ns10:version>1.0</ns10:version>

                    <ns10:Profile id="xccdf_1_profile_1">
                            <ns10:title>ACME Security Profile 1</ns10:title>
                            <ns10:description>The profile 1 contains rules to secure ACME</ns10:description>
                            <ns10:select idref="xccdf_1_rule_1401" selected="false"/>
                            <ns10:select idref="xccdf_1_rule_1402" selected="true"/>
                    </ns10:Profile>

                    <ns10:Group id="xccdf_1_group_1">

                            <ns10:Rule id="xccdf_1_rule_1401" selected="true" severity="medium">
                                    <ns10:title>1.4.01-s: verify rights and permissions on file /tmp/raymond.txt</ns10:title>
                                    <ns10:description>stat -c %a /tmp/raymond.txt</ns10:description>
                                    <ns10:fix system="urn:xccdf:fix:script:sh">date >> /tmp/raymond.txt; chmod 600 /tmp/raymond.txt; chown root:root /tmp/raymond.txt</ns10:fix>
                                    <ns10:check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
                                            <ns10:check-content-ref href="scap_1_catalog_1" name="oval:ray:def:1401"/>
                                    </ns10:check>
                            </ns10:Rule>

                            <ns10:Rule id="xccdf_1_rule_1402" selected="true" severity="medium">
                                    <ns10:title>selinux</ns10:title>
                                    <ns10:description>Checks if you have SELinux enabled</ns10:description>
                                    <ns10:check system="http://wordpress-www-open-scap-org.b9ad.pro-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/page/SCE">
                                            <ns10:check-import import-name="stdout" />
                                            <ns10:check-content-ref href="scap_1402.sh" />
                                    </ns10:check>
                            </ns10:Rule>

                    </ns10:Group>

            </ns10:Benchmark>

    </ns0:component>

    <ns0:component id="scap_1_comp_2" timestamp="2018-04-03T23:40:40">

            <oval_definitions      xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">

                    <generator>
                            <oval:product_name>ACME Hardening</oval:product_name>
                            <oval:schema_version>5.10.1</oval:schema_version>
                            <oval:timestamp>2018-04-10T08:00:00</oval:timestamp>
                    </generator>

                    <definitions>

                            <definition id="oval:ray:def:1401" version="1" class="compliance">
                                    <metadata>
                                            <title>1.4.01-s: 1.4.01-s: verify rights and permissions on file /tmp/raymond.txt</title>
                                            <description>stat -c %a /tmp/raymond.txt</description>
                                    </metadata>
                                    <criteria operator="AND">
                                            <criterion test_ref="oval:ray:tst:1401" comment="1401"/>
                                    </criteria>
                            </definition>

                    </definitions>

                    <tests>

                            <unix-def:file_test id="oval:ray:tst:1401" comment="oval:ray:tst:1.4.01" version="1" check="all">
                                    <unix-def:object object_ref="oval:ray:obj:1401"/>
                                    <unix-def:state state_ref="oval:ray:ste:1401"/>
                            </unix-def:file_test>

                    </tests>

                    <objects>

                            <unix-def:file_object id="oval:ray:obj:1401" version="1">
                                    <unix-def:filepath>/tmp/raymond.txt</unix-def:filepath>
                            </unix-def:file_object>

                    </objects>

                    <states>

                            <unix-def:file_state id="oval:ray:ste:1401" version="1">
                                    <unix-def:group_id operation="equals" datatype="int">0</unix-def:group_id>
                                    <unix-def:user_id operation="equals" datatype="int">0</unix-def:user_id>
                                    <unix-def:uexec operation="equals" datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:uexec>
                                    <unix-def:gwrite operation="equals" datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:gwrite>
                                    <unix-def:gexec operation="equals" datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:gexec>
                                    <unix-def:owrite operation="equals" datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:owrite>
                                    <unix-def:oexec operation="equals" datatype="boolean">false</unix-def:oexec>
                            </unix-def:file_state>

                    </states>

            </oval_definitions>

    </ns0:component>
```

The command I start is:

```
[root]# oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_1_profile_1 rm-ds.xml
```

the result I get is:

```
Title   selinux
Rule    xccdf_1_rule_1402
Result  notchecked
```

I think something is wrong around "Rule id="xccdf_1_rule_1402" but I don't understand the problem

The script file to execute (scap_1402.sh) is in the same directory as xml file, and has valid syntax and correct rights. In standalone mode, it works but it seems to never be called by oscap

The OS is centos

```
[root]# uname -a
Linux ip-127.0.0.1.compute.internal 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 19:03:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The scap installed  packages are:

```
[root]# yum list installed | grep scap
openscap.x86_64                    1.2.14-3.el7_4               @updates
openscap-engine-sce.x86_64         1.2.14-3.el7_4               @updates
openscap-scanner.x86_64            1.2.14-3.el7_4               @updates
scap-security-guide.noarch         0.1.33-6.el7.centos          @updates
```

Can somebody help me ?
BTW, excuse my english, it is not my natural language

Raymond

---

I updated, the error message is different (but still present)

xml file:

> ```
>         <ns10:Rule id="xccdf_1_rule_1402" selected="true" severity="medium">
>            <ns10:title>selinux</ns10:title>
>            <ns10:description>Checks if you have SELinux enabled</ns10:description>
>               <ns10:check system="http://open-scap.org/page/SCE">
>                  <ns10:check-import import-name="stdout" />
>                  <ns10:check-content-ref href="scap_1402.sh" />
>               </ns10:check>
>         </ns10:Rule>
> ```

output:

> [root]# oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_1_profile_1  rm-ds.xml Title 
>   selinux Rule    xccdf_1_rule_1402 Result  notchecked
>
> OpenSCAP Error: SCE couldn't find script file 'scap_1402.sh'. Expected
>   location: '/tmp/oscap.3sSrgD/scap_1402.sh'. [sce_engine.c:387]

Same kind of error message if I set absolute path /root/scap_1402.sh

Answer (score 1):

I think the URL in system attribute in check element is wrong.

```
<ns10:check system="http://wordpress-www-open-scap-org.b9ad.pro-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/page/SCE">
```

There should be

```
system="http://open-scap.org/page/SCE"
```

See https://github.com/OpenSCAP/openscap/blob/maint-1.2/tests/sce/sce_xccdf.xml for an example.

I wonder why is such a weird URL mentioned in https://www.open-scap.org/features/other-standards/sce/ page. I think there was a mistake when batch converting the links on OpenSCAP website.